# Audio recorded on button press missing some duration on my android device

Tags: java, android, voice-recording

I am facing an issue that on button touch i start recording audio in my android application, but when i plays the recorded audio it is missing some duration of the recorded audio.

Here is my code snippet to start recording voice on a button touch given by:

```
    public void start() {

    myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    try {
        myRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myRecorder.start();
    text.setText("Recording point: Recording...");

}
```

On sensing touch event i starts calling this **start();** function.
Can any body tell me any alternative solution? I faced this issue on my glaxy s3 android device.

Answer (score 1):

```
myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

The piece of code above takes some time, hence the delay between the user pressing the button (`start()` being called) and the recorder actually starting the recording (`myRecorder.start()`).

You should initialize the recorder and get it ready before the button is pressed. Just move the above piece of code elsewhere, e.g. `onCreate()`. Since I don't know the context of this code, I cannot tell you exactly where.